# Change Chartjs financial chart yaxis from left to right

Tags: javascript, chart.js, finance

Change Chartjs financial chart yaxis from left to the right, tried this code but didnt work:

scales: {
yAxes: [{
display: true,
position: 'right'
}]
}

https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-chart-financial/
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add position right to the first (default) yAxes object in the options

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        position: 'right'
      }]
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:** Seems like chartjs financial is working with v3 of the lib. In v3 you have to edit the axis in a different way:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      position: "right"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: on chartjs-financial doesnt work, maybe on chartjs alone

Comment: Updated answer for you after notecing they were based on the new beta instead of stable v2

Answer (score 0):

```
scales: {yAxes: [{
display: true,
position: 'right',
ticks: {
 beginAtZero: false,
 max: 2000,
 min: 1000,
 stepSize: 100
}}]}

scales: { yAxes: [{
display: true,
position: 'right',
ticks: {
 beginAtZero: true
},}]}
```

you can try these two ways, one of the them will work, depends on the your chart.